# Android device administrator - Disable camera not applied in (Multi-user) Guest account

Tags: android, security, android-camera, mdm, device-admin

I have implemented a device administrator application that disables the camera, among other things, based on certain requisites (server side logic) etc.

```
   devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
   devicePolicyAdmin = new ComponentName(this, MyDevicePolicyReceiver.class);
   devicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(devicePolicyAdmin, true);
```

Everything is working as intended. However, the user is able to circumvent the restriction by simply switching user profile in a multi user enabled phone model (e.g. to the Guest account). The list of device administrators in that account does not reflect the app too. This is deemed as a security breach by company policy.

I would like to know if:

1. Is there any specific code that can install the device administrator
   globally?
2. Is there any method that can prevent multi-user
       programmatically without rooting?
3. Is there any method that can
       prevent switching users or detecting a user switch etc as it
       happens, should 1 or 2 be impossible?

Any other suggestions would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is specific to Samsung devices but Samsung KNOX allows programmatically disabling multiple users on KNOX enabled devices.  I'm the author of an Android app locker and we just watch for launches of the user switching interface and trigger the app lock on that.

Comment: So the best solution would be to detect the user switch interface as not all devices are Samsung?

Comment: Also, does detecting the user switch interface work if the user switch is done without logging in? (If this is even possible)

Comment: Yes, it would be best to detect it or block it.  We block that by using Accessibility Services to watch for the switching screen. If you're interested in testing this just open a support ticket at www.aleph-com.net and reference this question.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Based on my research it is not possible to create a device administrator that has admin access across all accounts on the device. The comments/answer in this thread came to the same conclusion: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138417

(2/3) Looking through the DPM APIs it doesn't look like it's possible to prevent the user from switching or creating new accounts or listening for account switching. Preventing the user from switching or creating new accounts is possible through rooting your device by modifying `build.prop` with `fw.max_users=1` see: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119632
 and https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/323l36/android_5x_how_to_disable_guest_additional_user/

If you're against rooting devices because of the time/maintenance/security issues, I'd suggest looking at mobile device management tools. The comment above mentions Samsung Knox which will let you disable having multiple users on the device through their [MultiUserManager](https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/android/app/enterprise/multiuser/MultiUserManager.html).

You can also use [Mason](https://bymason.com/) to lock down your devices/applications by turning off multi-user, preventing the user from pulling down the status bar or accessing Settings, or locking your application in kiosk mode.

If this sounds useful to you, feel free to reach out to me: `trevor @ bymason.com`

**DISCLAIMER: I work for Mason**